# Nested array is not returning deepest obj

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am working with `lodash`, I am trying to obtain an object which is nested in an array. What I need is `betTypes`, so I put `var needDeepestObj` to get `betTypes` by using `_.filter`

```
var deepestObj = function(betSlipData) {

  var needDeepestObj = 

    _.filter(betSlipData.customerBetTypes, function(betIndex) {
      return _.filter(betIndex.betTypes, function(betTypes) {
         console.log('1', betTypes); //returns what I need
         return betTypes;
      });
    });

    console.log('2', needDeepestObj);
   //returns only the first _.filter with param *betIndex*
};
```

so, how can I reach the scope which contains `betTypes` ?

this is what `betIndex` param returns in my browser console.

```
{
  "header": {
    "name": "Straights",
    "priority": "1"
  },
  "betTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Straight",
      "buyPoints": "Y",
      "maxPoints": "3",
      "minPoints": "0",
      "isAvailable": "1",
      "placeBetIsAvailable": "1",
      "reasonPlaceBetNotAvailable": "",
      "isSelected": "0",
      "priority": 1
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "name": "Straights",
    "priority": "1"
  },
  "betTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Straight",
      "buyPoints": "Y",
      "maxPoints": "3",
      "minPoints": "0",
      "isAvailable": "1",
      "placeBetIsAvailable": "1",
      "reasonPlaceBetNotAvailable": "",
      "isSelected": "0",
      "priority": 1
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "name": "Straights",
    "priority": "1"
  },
  "betTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Straight",
      "buyPoints": "Y",
      "maxPoints": "3",
      "minPoints": "0",
      "isAvailable": "1",
      "placeBetIsAvailable": "1",
      "reasonPlaceBetNotAvailable": "",
      "isSelected": "0",
      "priority": 1
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "name": "Straights",
    "priority": "1"
  },
  "betTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Straight",
      "buyPoints": "Y",
      "maxPoints": "3",
      "minPoints": "0",
      "isAvailable": "1",
      "placeBetIsAvailable": "1",
      "reasonPlaceBetNotAvailable": "",
      "isSelected": "0",
      "priority": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

So, what I need is `betTypes`, and `betIndex` returns the JSON I pasted above.

**UPDATE**

Obviously, is a very big JSON, which contains like a thousand "header" and "betTypes" properties. But I need to iterate over that JSON in order to process only once that properties.

Comment: Can you give input and output you want ?

Comment: @Thom-x sorry but what do you mean ? I said above that what I need is `betTypes`, and `betIndex` returns the json I paste in my question.

Comment: I don't understand sorry :/... If you want `betTypes` then do `var result = betIndex.betTypes`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, see my update please @Thom-x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow your question exactly.
My answer is under the assumption thatL:

```
betSlipData.customerBetTypes = [{ header: {}, betTypes: [{}] }, ...]
```

then it's really simple:

```
var needDeepestObj = _(betSlipData.customerBetTypes).map(function (bet) {
    return bet.betTypes;
}).flatten().value();
```

This will produce an array of all objects from each array of betTypes within each bet.

It would help a lot if you could show an example of what betSlipData.customerBetTypes is and what the exact result is that you are looking for, whether it's an array or object, specific keys, etc.

Are you looking for a specific betType?